# Displaying list of firestore documents on angular webapp page

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

Unable to list all the documents on html page. It shows only first document. How do I list all the documents matching the criteria. Any help would be appreciated.

**I am fetching my firestore documents in the following way**

```
this.afs.collection('stories', ref => ref.where('userid', '==', this.userId))
      .get().toPromise()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          var sTname = doc.data().storyteller;
          var sTitle = doc.data().storytitle;
          var readyFile = doc.data().readyfilepath;
          var rawFile = doc.data().rawfilepath;

          document.getElementById("stname").innerHTML = sTname;
          document.getElementById("stitle").innerHTML = sTitle;
          document.getElementById("readyfile").innerHTML = readyFile;
          document.getElementById("rawfile").innerHTML = rawFile;

        });
      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error getting stories: ", error);
      });

  }
```

**and now I want to display all the documents on the html page for which I am using this**

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>My Stories</h2>
      <table class="table table-striped">
          <thread>
            <tr>
              <th>Story Teller Name</th>
              <th>Story Title</th>
              <th>Ready File</th>
              <th>Raw File </th>
             
              </tr>
          </thread>
          <tbody>
              <tr id="tr">
              <td id="stname"></td>
              <td id="stitle"></td>
              <td id="readyfile"></td>
              <td id="rawfile"></td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a single row in HTML and from your script you are setting column values. This will result in displaying only the last row.

Instead, you should dynamically create rows from your script. For each document a new row. There are couple of options:

- Method 1: Use `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` methods after obtaining the table object using `document.getElementById('tableId')`
- Method 2: Prepare the HTMl for all rows dynamically and then set `innerHTML` of `tbody`
- Method 3: Use `createElement()`, `createTextNode()` to create row, column, text values and then use `appendChild()` to append the element at the appropriate place.

Here is the running example with method #1 mentioned above. You may try in other ways too. In the example data is hardcoded in an array.

```js
function populateDataMethod1() {
  var data = [{ "storyteller": "M1:Name 1", "storytitle": "M1:Title 1", "readyFile": "M1:File 1", "rawfile": "M1:File A" },
        { "storyteller": "M1:Name 2", "storytitle": "M1:Title 2", "readyFile": "M1:File 2", "rawfile": "M1:File B" },
        { "storyteller": "M1:Name 3", "storytitle": "M1:Title 3", "readyFile": "M1:File 3", "rawfile": "M1:File C" }]
  var table = document.getElementById("data");
  data.forEach(doc => {
      var row = table.insertRow();
      row.insertCell().innerHTML = doc.storyteller;
      row.insertCell().innerHTML = doc.storytitle;
      row.insertCell().innerHTML = doc.readyFile;
      row.insertCell().innerHTML = doc.rawfile;
  });
  }

function populateDataMethod2() {
  var data = [{ "storyteller": "M2:Name 1", "storytitle": "M2:Title 1", "readyFile": "M2:File 1", "rawfile": "M2:File A" },
        { "storyteller": "M2:Name 2", "storytitle": "M2:Title 2", "readyFile": "M2:File 2", "rawfile": "M2:File B" },
        { "storyteller": "M2:Name 3", "storytitle": "M2:Title 3", "readyFile": "M2:File 3", "rawfile": "M2:File C" }]
  var table = document.getElementById("data-table");
  var dataHtml = "";
  data.forEach(doc => {
      dataHtml += "<tr><td>" + doc.storyteller + "</td><td>" + doc.storytitle + "</td><td>" +
          doc.readyFile + "</td><td>" + doc.rawfile + "</td></tr>";
  });
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = dataHtml;
  }

function populateDataMethod3() {
  var data = [{ "storyteller": "M3:Name 1", "storytitle": "M3:Title 1", "readyFile": "M3:File 1", "rawfile": "M3:File A" },
        { "storyteller": "M3:Name 2", "storytitle": "M3:Title 2", "readyFile": "M3:File 2", "rawfile": "M3:File B" },
        { "storyteller": "M3:Name 3", "storytitle": "M3:Title 3", "readyFile": "M3:File 3", "rawfile": "M3:File C" }]
  var table = document.getElementById("data-table");
  data.forEach(doc => {
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
      var column1 = document.createElement("td");
      var column2 = document.createElement("td");
      var column3 = document.createElement("td");
      var column4 = document.createElement("td");
      column1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.storyteller));
      column2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.storytitle));
      column3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.readyFile));
      column4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.rawfile));
      row.appendChild(column1);
      row.appendChild(column2);
      row.appendChild(column3);
      row.appendChild(column4);
      document.getElementById("data").appendChild(row);
  });
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Populate in Method 1" onclick="populateDataMethod1()" />
<input type="button" value="Populate in Method 2" onclick="populateDataMethod2()" />
<input type="button" value="Populate in Method 3" onclick="populateDataMethod3()" />
<table class="table table-striped" id="data-table">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            <th>Story Teller Name</th>
            <th>Story Title</th>
            <th>Ready File</th>
            <th>Raw File </th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody id="data">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @fiveelements for the help.

Comment: @amusicalwish good to know that your problem is resolved.